# What's on this pendant?

Tags: translation, meaning

I've ordered this item on famous chinese marketplace and now wondering what it actually means :) seller describe these characters as a 'mantra'.
Google Translate and Papago extracted characters in some glibberish way, imho (pics attached) or it's kind of prank from a seller, ha!
Btw, on the other side of this pendant are Eight Trigrams around Yin Yang symbol.
Thanks!
[image: original]
[[image: kinda translated][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9jEQ.png)

Comment: it is not gibberish, but is seal script-- I personally am not super good at it and a computer will 100% fail

Comment: Didn't know about that, thank to you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

臨兵闘者皆陣列前行

Each word carries profound meanings in Daoism an Buddhism, not really related to its regular usage.

It's attested as early as 東晉葛洪(283AD－343AD)《抱朴子》, which is a classic of Daoism.

> 臨兵闘者，皆陣列前行。凡九字，常當密祝之，無所不辟。

That is regularly saying the 9 words can expel any evil.

Comment: I'm impressed, thank you for such detailed answer!